# Using VBA how to prevent a message from appearing when opening a file?

Tags: excel, messagebox, suppressmessage, vba

I'm creating a macro which opens numerous files, refreshes them, and then saves and closes. All is running smoothly however for 2 of the files when they are opened a message pops up which reads "Files run on an inclusion list - titles may be missing." this halts the macro until "ok" is pressed. I have used "Application.DisplayAlerts = False" before but it doesn't seem to be working here. My code is as follows:

```
Public Sub Refresh_All()

Dim filepathstr As String
Dim filename As String
Dim wbk As Workbook

filepathstr = Sheet1.Range("filepath").Value

For Each cell In Sheet1.Range("workbooks")

If Not cell.Value = "" Then

    filename = cell.Value
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(filepathstr & filename, False)


    ''''**REFRESH**''''''
    SAPBexrefresh (True)

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wbk.Save
    wbk.Close False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End If

Next cell

MsgBox "The Macro has finished; BW Reports are refreshed."


End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do those files have macros that might be causing those pop ups?

Comment: Ah yes they do didn't even check that, thanks I think I just need to delete/ turn off the macro in them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

```
Application.EnableEvents=False
```

before opening the wb and set back to true afterwards

Alternatively, use:

```
Application.AutomationSecurity=msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable
```

Remember to set back to whatever the user has...