# Press cancel on Open dialog that pops up in a loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops, worksheet

I have code which asks to choose .xlsx files to perform character replacement in selected files.

When it goes through worksheets, open dialog pops up asking to open file as many times as worksheets are in selected files.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ReplaceCharactersInSelectedFiles()
    Dim FileDialog As FileDialog
    Dim SelectedFiles As FileDialogSelectedItems
    Dim AccChars As String
    Dim RegChars As String
    Dim NewFileName As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim OriginalCalculationMode As XlCalculation
    Dim CurrentWorkbook As Workbook
    
    ' Store the original calculation mode and set to manual to improve performance
    OriginalCalculationMode = Application.Calculation
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    ' Ask the user to select multiple .xlsx files
    Set FileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    FileDialog.Title = "Select .xlsx Files"
    FileDialog.Filters.Clear
    FileDialog.Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xlsx"
    
    If FileDialog.Show = -1 Then
        Set SelectedFiles = FileDialog.SelectedItems
        
        ' Read AccChars from cell B10 of the active worksheet
        AccChars = ActiveSheet.Range("B10").Value

        ' Read RegChars from cell B11 of the active worksheet
        RegChars = ActiveSheet.Range("B11").Value

        ' Loop through the selected files
        For i = 1 To SelectedFiles.Count
            ' Open the workbook in read-only mode without displaying it
            Set CurrentWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(SelectedFiles(i), ReadOnly:=True)
            
            ' Loop through all sheets in the workbook
            For Each ws In CurrentWorkbook.Sheets
                ' Perform character replacement in the current sheet
                StripAccent ws.UsedRange, AccChars, RegChars
            Next ws
            
            ' Save the modified file with "noChar" added to its filename
            NewFileName = Left(CurrentWorkbook.FullName, InStrRev(CurrentWorkbook.FullName, ".") - 1) & "_noChar.xlsx"
            CurrentWorkbook.SaveAs NewFileName
            CurrentWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Next i
    End If

    ' Restore the original calculation mode
    Application.Calculation = OriginalCalculationMode
End Sub

Sub StripAccent(aRange As Range, ByVal AccChars As String, ByVal RegChars As String)
    Dim A As String * 1
    Dim B As String * 1
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To Len(AccChars)
        A = Mid(AccChars, i, 1)
        B = Mid(RegChars, i, 1)
        aRange.Replace What:=A, Replacement:=B, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=True
    Next
End Sub
```

I have to press cancel as many times as worksheets in selected files.

Comment: This may help you answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40384205/using-vba-how-to-prevent-a-message-from-appearing-when-opening-a-file